# Scraping multiple links

Tags: python, loops, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, pagination

i have to scrape the CCI website (https://www.cci.fr/agent-immobilier?company_name=agences%20immobili%C3%A8res%20&brand_name=&siren=&numero_carte=&code_region=84&city=&code_postal=&person_name=&state_recherche=1&name_region=AUVERGNE-RHONE-ALPES&page=0) and i need to go to each attestation (link with the "Attestation de ...") scrape the whole page and go back to the main page (the first link) and keep doing this for all the pages en for all the links of the website. So i managed to do it for one link and go back, but i'm struggling to do it for the whole first page then the other pages until there's no more page left. Also, it might take days, or maybe weeks cause i have to do it for all of the regions, i heard about multiprocessing but i'm struggling to implement it, anyways, i might need some help. Thank you ! Here's my code btw:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
import time
with open('output_test_auvergne.csv', 'w') as file:
    file.write("business_names; town_pc; region \n")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())  # initialise chrome driver
driver.get(
    'https://www.cci.fr/agent-immobilier?company_name=agences%20immobili%C3%A8res%20&brand_name=&siren=&numero_carte=&code_region=84&city=&code_postal=&person_name=&state_recherche=1&name_region=AUVERGNE-RHONE-ALPES&__cf_chl_captcha_tk__=pmd_74hrnIdUsNgz2TJJCM33kpVYFY4hRG420hx18Sk1ITA-1634596843-0-gqNtZGzNBBCjcnBszQil')
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(3)
cookie = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='tarteaucitronPersonalize2']")
try:
    cookie.click()
finally:
    pass
visited_pages = ['1']
with open('output_test_auvergne.csv', 'w') as file:
    while True:
        table_rows = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('table tr')
        business_name = None
        for row in table_rows: #loop for identifying elements 
            try:
                business_name = row.find_element_by_css_selector('.titre_entreprise').text
                continue
            except:
                pass
            try:
                if row.get_attribute('class') == 'lien-fiche':
                    for index, td in enumerate(row.find_elements_by_css_selector('td')):
                        if index == 0:
                            attestation_name = td.text
                        if index == 1:
                            city = td.text
                        if index == 2:
                            region = td.text
            except:
                pass
            link2 = row.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="main-content"]/div[5]/table/tbody/tr/td/a')
            for links2 in link2:
                link2.click()                                        
                num_attestation = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="agent-immobilier__document"]/div[2]/div[1]/strong').text
                date_delivrance = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="agent-immobilier__document"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/strong').text
                delivre_par = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="agent-immobilier__document"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/strong').text
                date_disponibilite = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="agent-immobilier__document"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/strong').text
                president = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="agent-immobilier__document"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/strong').text
                fonction = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="agent-immobilier__document"]/div[2]/div[3]/div[3]/strong').text
                etendue_pouvoir = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="agent-immobilier__document"]/div[2]/div[3]/div[4]/strong').text
                num_carte_pro = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="agent-immobilier__document"]/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/strong[1]').text
                dispo_carte_pro = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="agent-immobilier__document"]/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/strong[2]').text
                date_delivrance_carte_pro = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="agent-immobilier__document"]/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/div[2]/strong').text
                organisme_delivrance = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="agent-immobilier__document"]/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/div[3]/strong').text
                titulaire_carte = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="agent-immobilier__document"]/div[2]/div[4]/div[2]/div[2]/strong[1]').text
                forme_juridique = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="agent-immobilier__document"]/div[2]/div[4]/div[2]/div[2]/strong[2]').text
                adresse = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="agent-immobilier__document"]/div[2]/div[4]/div[2]/div[4]/strong/div[1]').text
                nom_commercial = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="agent-immobilier__document"]/div[2]/div[4]/div[2]/div[5]/strong[1]').text
                num_identification = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="agent-immobilier__document"]/div[2]/div[4]/div[2]/div[5]/strong[2]').text
                representant_legal_nom = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="agent-immobilier__document"]/div[2]/div[5]/div/strong[1]').text
                representant_legal_prnom = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="agent-immobilier__document"]/div[2]/div[5]/div/strong[2]').text
                garantie_fonciere = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="agent-immobilier__document"]/div[2]/div[6]/div[2]/div[3]/strong').text
                detention_fonds = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="agent-immobilier__document"]/div[2]/div[6]/div[2]/div[2]').text
                assurance_nom = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="agent-immobilier__document"]/div[2]/div[7]/div[3]/strong').text
                adresse_assurance = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="agent-immobilier__document"]/div[2]/div[7]/div[4]/strong').text
                cp_ville_assurance = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="agent-immobilier__document"]/div[2]/div[7]/div[6]/strong').text
                                        
                driver.back();   
                                        
                file.write(business_name + ";" + attestation_name + ';' + city + ";" + region + ";" + num_attestation + ";" + date_delivrance + ";" + delivre_par + ";" + date_disponibilite + ";" (president) + ";" + fonction + ";" + etendue_pouvoir + ";" + num_carte_pro + ";" + dispo_carte_pro + ";" + date_delivrance_carte_pro + ";" +  organisme_delivrance + ";" + titulaire_carte + ";" + forme_juridique + ";" + adresse + ";" + nom_commercial + ";" + num_identification + ";" + representant_legal_nom + ";" + representant_legal_prnom + ";" +  garantie_fonciere + ";" + detention_fonds + ";" + assurance_nom + ";" + adresse_assurance + ";" + cp_ville_assurance + "\n")
                pass
                                
                number_of_pages = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a[rel='next']").click()
                current_page = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a[title="Page courante"]').text
                if current_page in visited_pages:
                    break
                visited_pages =+ current_page
                file.close()
                driver.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can scrape the data easier by the help of [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).
Scraping faster can be accomplished by using [aiohttp](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/) with the help of `asyncio`. An [example video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6ow7xloFy5s).